android studio: When I run the app in the emulator, the edittext, textview and buttons are not displayed
I'm new to programming in Android Studio. I'm about to build a simple calculator that adds two numbers, I made the graphical diagram and ran it on the emulator to see if everything was going well but
When I run the app in the emulator, the edittext, textview and buttons are not displayed. please helpme
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtnumerodos"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.884"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Kalkuladora.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblprimernumero"
        android:layout_width="131dp"

        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:text="ingrese primer numero"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.167"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.053" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="ingrese el segundo numero"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.201"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.126" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtnumerouno"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.857"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsumar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sumar"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 

   package com.kalkuladora;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.kalkuladora.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}



I think you are forgetting to Override the onCreate method and using setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

I'm new to Android programming. Could you be more specific about what to do with onCreate ?
Could you write the code for what it says regarding :
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

The onCreate method is extended from the activity class check this question is called when the app is opened (not the only case) and is used to load your layout (your .xml file)
